# JRumble and position fixed/absolute in css don't work together

Tags: jquery, absolute

I designed my site logo with position: absolute but when i used Jrumble to shake it, it's shaking but css position disabled.

Here is my js codes:

```
$('#log').jrumble();
var demoStart = function(){
    $('#log').trigger('startRumble');
    setTimeout(demoStop, 500);
};

var demoStop = function(){
    $('#log').trigger('stopRumble');
    setTimeout(demoStart, 10000);
};

demoStart();
```

and css codes:

```
#log {
position: absolute;
width: 650px;
right: 25px;
top: -15px;
```

}

whats wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, jRumble depends on the element being positioned with `relative`. It will force it to that state when run. You can work around it by putting all of your absolute position rules on a wrapper element, then applying the jRumble effect directly tothe child element of that absolutely positioned element.

**View the demo here:** http://jsfiddle.net/Kw6eb/

**HTML**

```
<div id="log-wrap">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/300" id="log">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#log-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    right: 100px;
    top: 100px;
}

#log {
    width: 250px;
}
```

Your JavaScript can stay the same. I adjusted the width and position values for the demo to show that it is working better. Adjust those for your needs.

Comment: you say i have to put my elements -who jrumbled- inside another div. i did it already but its extra job and i dont wanna do that. Is there a real solution or do i have to do this?

Comment: That is the only solution I can think of. I was going to write a more robust version 2 recently, but an even better CSS based shake was written here: http://elrumordelaluz.github.io/csshake/ I'd give that a try.